# $.unique(array) is not working for array elements having multiple words

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

```
 var availableNames=['Hello India', 'Hello India', 'Test', 'Test']
    $.unique(availableNames);
    $("#corpName").autocomplete({
                source : availableNames,
                minLength : 4
            });
```

availableNames is my array source for auto-complete. I want to show unique values in the list so called jquery unique function. 
The unique function is working fine for single words like 'Hello' but not for two word strings like 'Hello India'. Its showing two 'Hello India' in dropdown and one 'Hello'.

Please Suggest me how to display only unique values in the drop-down list.
Thank You.

Comment: "This function *only works on plain JavaScript arrays of DOM elements*, and is chiefly used internally by jQuery. You probably will never need to use it." (emphasis mine). Nevertheless, `$.unique(availableNames)` shows `["Test", "Hello India"]`; please create a fiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: [Your code works here](http://jsbin.com/wacanabosu/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: insert the String "Test" between the two "Hello India" Strings and it will become a duplicate. Trust the manual. It's not properly working with arrays of Strings.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write your own function. There are two ways to do that:

use filter:

```
// returns a new array with unique entries
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
  return this.filter(function(el, index, oThis) {
    return index === oThis.indexOf(el);
  });
}
```

**EDIT** here is a real prototype version, that changes the original array

```
Array.prototype.unique2 = function() {
    var c=this.length;
    while(c--)
        c===this.indexOf(this[c])||this.splice(c,1);
};
```

you can test both versions in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6mpqaxhk/